# Is it safe to truncate torchaudio's loaded 16-bit audios to `float16` from `float32`?

Tags: python, audio, pytorch, wav, torchaudio

I have multiple WAV files with 16 bits of depth/precision. `torchaudio.info(...)` recognizes this, giving me:

```
precision = {int} 16
```

Yet when I use `torchaudio.load(...)`, I get a `float32` dtype for the resulting tensor.
With a tensor called `audio`, I know that I can do `audio.half()` to truncate it to 16 bits, reducing memory usage of my dataset. But is this an operation that will preserve precision of all possible original values? I'm not lowering the dtype's precision below the original audio's precision, but there may be a good reason I'm unaware of as to why `torchaudio` still returns `float32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's returned as float32 because this is pytorch's default datatype. So if you create any models with weights, they'll be float32 as well. Therefore, the inputs will be incompatible with the model if you make the conversion on the input data. (E: or it will silently convert your data to 32 bit anyway, to make it compatible with your model. Not sure which pytorch opt for, but tensorflow definitely throws the error).

Look at setting the default datatype to float16, before creating any models, if you're looking to make small models: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_dtype.html

HOWEVER note that you *will* lose 5 bits of precision if you convert a 16-bit int, as you have diagnosed that the number actually is (but is represented as a 32-bit float), to a 16-bit float. This is because 5 bits of precision are used in the exponent, leaving just 10 bits to represent the decimal part representing the number.

I would just keep it at float32, if you're not particularly memory constrained.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, never realized that the underlying values in the WAV format were actually `int16`. It looks like the process of converting this to a float is called normalization. I will stick to `float32`, but can that perfectly represent every `int16`? Or does it still lose some precision, but much less than `float16`?

Comment: int 16 is 1 sign bit and 15 bits of binary digits. [float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is 1 sign bit, 8 for the exponent, and 23 remaining for the digits. So to me it looks like you can fit the 15 original bits in the 23-bit number chunk, with bits to spare. No precision loss, I believe.